# Underlying type of std::optional in template

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a generic code that executes the passsed lambda and checks the outputs. I would like the helper method to be fully deduced, but cannot come up with the solution since the method returns `std::optional` and I want the processing method to return the underlying type of it. Code:

```
#include <optional>
#include <type_traits>

std::optional<int> dummy() { return {42}; };

template<typename F, typename Ret = std::result_of_t<F(void)>>
static Ret process(const F& f)
{
  Ret val{};
  if(auto res = f(); res) { val = *res;}
  return val;
}
int main()
{
  // call
  auto result = process(&dummy);
}
```

The `result` is of course type of `std::optional<int>`. What should I change in my template definition to deduce the return type of process to underlying type of `std::optional` - `int`?

Comment: Please try to copy/paste the code you actually showed in your question, and attempt to compile it. It won't work. Obvious typos. Please show real code in your question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yop, typo in `Ret`. Now it compiles.

Comment: No, it doesn't compile.  That's just one of an amazing number of typos and errors, above. You've been on stackoverflow.com for seven years, and you still are not familiar with the requirements for a [mre]?

Comment: Well, `main` added.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What are you talking about, after the `Ret` typo fix, it was perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All standard containers keep information about underlying data type on `value_type` typedef.

Why not write:

```
template<typename F, typename Ret = typename std::result_of_t<F(void)>::value_type >
```

then for `optional<int>`, `Ret` is `int`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Qyeipz)